# addclass depending on dynamic values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table populated with dates from a database query. I'm trying to add a class depending on the date. This script is working when i type in the dates but not when it gets populated from the db query?

Thankful for any help!

```
jQuery.each($('tbody tr td span'), function () {
    if (this.textContent < "2018") {
        $(this).addClass("badgeRed");
    }
    else if (this.textContent < "2019") {
                $(this).addClass("badgeYellow");
        } 
    else {
                $(this).addClass("badgeGreen");
        }
});
```

Comment: It's hard to diagnose the problem without seeing a more complete example of the code. How do you add the new `span`? What events are fired? Do the elements you're targeting exist when this code runs?

Comment: You need to parse the date as an integer. Use `parseInt()`.

Comment: can you show us what you are populating from db query?

Comment: What is the result of console.log(this.textContent); ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood: first of all you have to parse your date string and take the year from it like this:

```
successResponseFromServer (date) {
  let parsedDate = Date.parse(date); // parsing datestring to Date object
  let year = parsedDate.getFullYear(); // getting a year from the Date object
  jQuery.each($('tbody tr td span'), function () {
    if (year < 2018) {
      $(this).addClass("badgeRed");
    } else if (year < 2019) {
      $(this).addClass("badgeYellow");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("badgeGreen");
    }
  }); 
}
```

Show us more code, what type of date you are receiving, what type of span you are trying to change etc.